# Docker: Installed component of parent image disappear after run container

Tags: asp.net, docker, dockerfile, asterisk

I want to make a docker image that contains an Asp.net core app and some other components. I have decided to pull the debian image, install the necessary components (in this case is the asterisk system), then commit and push it as my own image, let's call it A.
In the Asp.net core app, I use A as a parent component in dockefile and build a image, let's call it B.

But when I run B as a container, I can not find the components I already installed in the image A.

This is my dockerfile:

```
FROM vocaoson7/asterisk:king
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive
RUN apt-get update

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1 AS build
WORKDIR /app

# copy csproj and restore as distinct layers
COPY *.sln .
COPY aspnetapp/*.csproj ./aspnetapp/
RUN dotnet restore

# copy everything else and build app
COPY aspnetapp/. ./aspnetapp/
WORKDIR /app/aspnetapp
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out


FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1 AS runtime
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build /app/aspnetapp/out ./
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "aspnetapp.dll"]
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to use a multi-stage build and the way it works is that your final image is defined by your last `FROM` command in your Dockerfile and whatever follows that.

So for your case, all you will find in your final image is the aspnet:3.1 installation (from the base image used for the runtime stage) and an /app folder containing with what your build step generated in the `out` directory.

Your very first `FROM` has no influence whatsoever on the final image.

Comment: I got it.
Do you have any suggestions for me to achieve my goal as I described above?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know ASP.NET, but so far my advice would be to build everything in 1 image (no multi stage). Once you've got that running you can look at optimizing the process. Regarding the debian image: shouldn't that be another container altogether? (sorry if this is a silly question but I really don't know how this should work)

Comment: Thanks, Mihai. Actually it's not a silly question. I just researched and realized the Debian image should be a separate container (using the docker-compose.yml file).